# How to fill in values from table B into table A based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a matrix A that is composed of let's say one column A.ID. I added another column `A.BIRTHDATE` with the `ALTER TABLE` Command (see below).

Now, I would like to fill in `A.BIRTHDATE` with the matching birthdates in table B that is composed of `B.ID` and `B.BIRTHDATE`.

There are plenty of similar examples in this forum but none of them worked for me. I do not know whether it has something to do with Oracle-SQL or because of minor differences in the questions asked.

One of the suggested solutions utilizes `UPDATE SET` and a `JOIN` (see second code line).

I get an error message stating that a subquery got more than one result per record. How to fix this?

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD BIRTHDATE DATE NULL;

UPDATE A
    SET A.BIRTHDATE = (
        SELECT B.BIRTHDATE
        FROM B
        WHERE A.ID= B.ID
        );
```

Comment: The message seems pretty clear.  You have duplicate `id`s in `B`.  You need to decide what to do about that.

Comment: Have you tried with DISTINCT? `SELECT  DISTINCT B.BIRTHDATE
        FROM B
        WHERE A.ID= B.ID`

Comment: Assuming IDs are primary keys in both tables they should enforce uniqueness. If this is not the case, try adding `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is issue of multiple records with same `ID` in table B.

You need to decide which record from table B is of your interest.

You can use `merge` statement to update values in table A as following:

```
Merge into A
Using (select id, 
              min(birthdate) as birthdate -- you can also use max or any logic of your interest
From B)
On (a.id=b.id)
When matched then
Update set a.birthdate = b.birthdate;
```

Also, update statement should be something like this:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.BIRTHDATE = (
        SELECT min(B.BIRTHDATE) -- or max or other logic
        FROM B
        WHERE A.ID= B.ID
        );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I see - you limit multiple matches to the minimum. This actually works for me because such records should belong to the same people, therefore have the same birthdate.

Comment: I was wondering; the min command causes large computational expenses. Per match, duplicates should have the same value. Therefore min(x) = max(x). Is there a faster logic that I can use?

Comment: Use distinct `ID, BIRTHDATE` and remove `GROUP BY`